# How to access Chatter blacklist keywords to moderate Chatter Answers for a community?

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups, chatter-answers

The chatter moderation criteria/rules appear to only impact Chatter forums and not Chatter Answers.  I can create a trigger on Questions and Replies for Chatter Answers though.  I haven't found a way to access the blacklisted words in the keyword list which is populated in the moderation criteria area for Chatter.

I'd like to avoid having two blacklisted word lists, one for chatter forums and one for chatter answers.  Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: They show how to moderate private chatter messages using blacklisted words below, and I think I can use a similar technique but what they don't show is how to populate that blacklist with the words from the moderation/criteria list:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_chattermessage_triggers.htm?search_text=words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the example doesn't really show where to store your blacklist.  Leaves it up to you to decide.

Are the two lists the same? If so just have a single list and store in custom settings.  If the two lists are different than it will be hard to just have a single list..

Also you might want to look at this package as an example or solution:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JqdAEAS

Comment: The problem is not where to store my blacklist, it's where to find it.  I've already got a blacklist in Salesforce.  I access it through the UI in the moderation criteria section of my community.  How can I access this list through SOQL or using APEX and one of the Salesforce APIs, like the ConnectAPI?  Or by any other reasonable means?

Comment: Gotcha.. I don't see any way to access the community keyword list at this time.  http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_connect_in_apex_classes.htm

Answer (score 0):

for accessing the file programmatically you already have in Salesforce, have you tried SOAP api? (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_document.htm) ?

Comment: this needs some more clarification as to how it applies to accessing the blacklist

Comment: how do you store blacklist? As of today moderation interface cannot read blacklisted words from a file.